# How adding two buttons at the end of listview in the second activity2?

Tags: android

How adding two buttons at the end of listview in the second activity2

Class:

```
    public class PedidosListActivity extends ListActivity implements  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder {
    private Button buttonAdicionarProduto;
    public class PedidosListActivity extends ListActivity implements  
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder {
    private Button buttonAdicionarProduto;
    private static final List<Map<String, Object>> produtos =  new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, produtos, R.layout.pedidos_list, de, para);
        adapter.setViewBinder(this);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

XML:

It consists of four components: the image view and three text view
I used List Activity Activity but when I can see on the screen, but without the adapter. With the adapter I do not know the time that the view will be ready to handle

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/query_result"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="br.edu.ifpe.pdm.cardapiolanches.PedidosListActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagem_produto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nome_produto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/peso"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/preco"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can't add buttons outside of a `ListView` when you use a `ListActivity`.  You would need to change to using a different type of Activity, and put the `ListView` and the buttons in the xml layout of the Activity.

Comment: sir im really not getting you, are you saying you want to add buttons below your listview? also are you saying that, you are able to see the screen when you do not set the adapter? or you are not able to see your items when you set your adapter? and also what do you want people to help you with, what do you want exactly Sir?

Comment: Only add two buttons after load items. the items are normal ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like one of the guys said in the comment, if you want to do something like this:

[image: Image example]

You'll have to change your class from ListActivity to [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) or [`ActionBarActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html). After that, try something like that in your XML file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_id"
                android:text="@string/home_text_2"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/lv_id"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

    <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_default"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Button Text"
                    android:id="@+id/bt_1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_default"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Button Text"
                    android:id="@+id/bt_2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```